# Experiences with db4o in production environment

Tags: mongodb, db4o

We are planning to migrate from Prevayler (http://prevayler.org/) to db4o (http://www.db4o.com/), so we wanted to know experiences, pros and cons, and best practices to move forward. What do you think about it? Is it a good solution? Or, maybe moving forward with a NoSQL standard solution would be better? (Such as MongoDB or CouchDB). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

we use db4o as main db in our production environment (both embedded and client/server), so i am going to share some of my experiences.

**Pro**:
- very easy for development (you just implememt data classes)
- support both embedded/client server under the same interface, which makes it easy to unittest
- decent performance for small projects

**Cons**:
- db4o is no longer developed so it's quite dead project, and you wont get much of support for it
- [client/server] everytime you change model you need to redeploy server (not talking about the fact that you need to host server app yourself)
- [client/server] performance degrade with more clients connected - not possible to scale

**Summary**: db4o is very good as embedded db (mobile app, desktop local db), but if it comes to server application you get into troubles

Comment: Okay! Good to know. We did an small PoC, and it does not work at all (at least, for us). The objects tree that you are handling it is quite big!? Finally, we choose Couchbase, which gave us some headaches, but so far is going quite good!

Answer (score 0):

Given that I did not receive so much feedback, we gave it a try. So far, it seemed to be a good option for a embedded database, that makes much easier the deployment. So, we wrote again the whole persistence layer, with their unit tests and seemed to work fine.
Then, we tried with real data, and we start to have some weird Null Pointers, and we did not know why. Then, we started to read and we found this issue: http://www.gamlor.info/wordpress/2009/09/db4o-activation-update-depth/.
We've been trying to solve for a few hours, but then we decided no to spend more time on it, and found another way. CouchDB, OrientDB or MongoDB are still on our list.